# Visual Studio C# variable in properties

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2013

Is there any functionality to use a global variable in form properties window?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form    
{
    string title = "This is title";
    // constructor,etc.
}
```

[image: variable as property]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't such functionality in the designer. The nearest you can get is using resources. You can't wire your resources directly in the designer (unless you are doing localization tricks), but you can edit your `Designer.cs` file and change:

```
this.MainForm.Text = "whatever";
```

for

```
this.MainForm.Text = Properties.Resources.MainFormTitle;
// or whatever other resource property you wish
```

This only works for resources (they are considered `Global Objects` by the designer and respected upon serializing): if you try to set any other variable (not a resource-generated property), it'll get overriden when the form is serialized again (upon saving).

Otherwise, you can just set your properties in the constructor, after `InitializeComponents()`, but they won't be seen in design-time unless you are inheriting that form.

Comment: All explained. Thanks.